# VBA Issue when Calculating

Tags: excel, vba

On the Model.Calculate Line, I get an error.

The error is "Cannot execute code in breakmode"

Anything wrong with the code? NOTE: TM1 Addin Is enabled and must be.

```
Sub Status_Quo_Sensitivity()

Dim wb As Workbook, Summary As Worksheet, Inputs As Worksheet, Model As Worksheet
Dim SenRange As Range, Reductions(1 To 5) As Double
Dim ReducCell As Range

Dim val As Integer, num As Integer


Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")
Set Inputs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUTS")
Set Model = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MODEL")

Set SenRange = Summary.Range("K15:K19")
Set ReducCell = Inputs.Range("D17")

For val = 1 To 5
    Reductions(val) = Summary.Cells(13, val + 8).Value
Next val


For num = LBound(Reductions) To UBound(Reductions)
    Inputs.Cells("D17") = Reductions(num)
    Model.Calculate
    Summary.Calculate
    SenRange.Copy
    Inputs.Range(Inputs.Cells(15, 8 + num), Inputs.Cells(19, 8 + num)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next num
```

Comment: Getting out of the error isnt so much a problem for me, I need to know why the error occurs

Comment: Are you using Solver?

Comment: ................... No

Answer (score 0):

```
Inputs.Cells("D17")
```

to

```
Inputs.Range("D17")
```

Comment: That does need to be changed and have already done so, but that has nothing to do with the error I am encountering

Comment: @Brreze32, refer [Breakmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#break-mode)